# Difference between getting bean through Controller method and applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Have issues getting bean instances from Controller methods over SpringApplicationContext. What I require in my Controller method is a well populated instance of class `B`. Definition of class `B` is below:

```
@Component
public class ADep {

}

@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private ADep aDep;

    public void printDep() {
        System.out.println("aDep is " + aDep);
    }
}

@Component
public class B extends A {
    public void printAMethod() {
        super.printDep();
    }
}
```

When the following Controller method is invoked:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, path = "/method1")
public MappingJacksonValue method1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, B b) throws Exception {
    b.printAMethod();
    return null;
}
```

I see the following response:

```
aDep is null
```

Instead of getting the bean in the Controller method, if I get it from application context, the response is different:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, path = "/hardware")
public MappingJacksonValue getHardware(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    B b = applicationContext.getBean(B.class);
    b.printAMethod();
    return null;
}
```

Result:

```
aDep is ADep@2e468dfa
```

What I require is a bean instance as in the later case. How can I get this in the Controller method without using SpringApplicationContext?

Comment: In your first case `b` is a parameter of the method. Can't tell how you call that method, but most probably you pass `null` into it

Comment: A method argument will never be autowired, onluy classlevel dependencies will. Unless you resort to full blown AspectJ usage (compile or loadtimeweaving) and use `@Configured`. So why do you need B for both binding and autowiring?

Comment: @M.Deinum, didn't know that the instances are made available differently in case of method invocation over Autowired instance variable. Is there any way to get Autowire kind of functionality for method argument? Tried Autowire in the method variable, but didn't have any difference.

Comment: There isn't. You cannot inject a bean into a method argument. Unless you write your own implementation of a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which does that. But why do you need an autowired object in the method anyway? Instead of injecting it at the classlevel.

Comment: I am unable to set the scope of class B to request. Hence, any value set in the previous requests are preserved in the instance variable of class B.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass the b object of type B as a parameter, so you must create and give the b object in this case and pass it to the method, I think you are giving this argument a null value, but if you want you can use @Autowired instead of application context, because B is already a component, like this:

```
@Autowired
private B b;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, path = "/hardware")
public MappingJacksonValue getHardware(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    b.printAMethod();
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To change the scope of the bean, a different bean for different request you can add the `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)` annotation above the `B` class

Comment: True that the bean gets injected well here. With the default scope, the same instance gets shared across requests and thus preserves fields set in previous requests.

Comment: You can change the scope of the bean B ,if you want, to request scoped.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in your method is provided by Spring MVC argument resolver. It doesn't inject bean here. I'm a little suprised that b is not null in this case, maybe the default behavior is creating a new instance of this class, and in this case, of course, aDep is null.